# I want to find the first period $T_0$ in a signal $x[n]$ and save it to a vector?

Tags: matlab, frequency

I want to find the first period $T_0$ in a signal $x[n]$ and save it to a vector $\hat x$?  $x[n]$ is read in by the command:

```
[x, fs] = audioread('Data/sample1.wav');
```

First of all, I have calculated the main frequency of the signal x[n]. I did it by

```
[x, fs] = audioread('Data/sample1.wav');
N = length(x);
f = (0:(N-1))*fs/N;
xdft = fft(x);
[~,index] = max(abs(xdft(1:length(x)/2+1)));
freq = 0:(fs/length(x)):fs/2;
```

Ok. `freq` is now my main frequency. As a next step, I want to calculate `T_0`.

```
T_0 = 1/fs;
```

And now I have to find this sequence, but how to do this? If I guess the signal in the wave is sines or cosines, but I do not know how to check this.

Comment: shouldn't be `T_0`as `T_0 = 1/freq`

Comment: @Zeeshan if you write an answer. I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time period should be inverse of the signal's frequency

> T_0 = 1/freq

not sampling frequency